# Basic CSS: making a horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to coding, trying to make a horizontal list for a course.  Can someone take a look at it for me and let me know what's wrong with my code?

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
            .menubar {  list-style:none;
            float:left;
            border-left:1px solid; 
            display:inline;}
        .numbers {display:inline;
            list-style-position:}           
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="whitebar">
        </div>
        <div class = "fixedwidth">  </div>
        <div id="home">  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="redbar"> List   </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="menubar">
            <li> Home </li>
            <li> Video</li>
            <li> World </li>
            <li> US & Canada </li>
            <li> UK </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're going to need to be more specific than "what is wrong" please. Specifically, where do you want the line? Have you run your code through a validator to eliminate basic syntactical errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `class="numbers"` to each of the `li` elements. Or you could use a new class named `menu-item` or something like that, where you have `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.